# prevent double click on animation but allow again

Tags: jquery

I have an fixed menu i hide and when i click the #menu-trigger , it pulls the menu out from the side of page. If i click #menu-trigger or #menu-overlay then i hide the menu again. When i single or double click the #menu-trigger , it hides the menu and runs animation one time , but when i double click the #menu-overlay it animates it twice sliding everything off the page too much.

I tried using .one click function but when i reopen the menu, i can not shut it using the overlay.

```
jQuery('#menu-trigger').click(function() {
    if ($(this).css('margin-right') == '250px') {
        $('#menu').animate({
            "margin-right": '-=250'
        });
        $('#menu-trigger').animate({
            'margin-right': '-=250'
        });
        $("#skinSelectorContainer").hide();
    } else {
        $('#menu').animate({
            'margin-right': '+=250'
        });
        $('#menu-trigger').animate({
            'margin-right': '+=250'
        });
    }
    $('#menu-overlay').fadeToggle();
});


jQuery('#menu-overlay').click(function() {
    $('#menu').animate({
        "margin-right": '-=250'
    });
    $('#menu-trigger').animate({
        'margin-right': '-=250'
    });
    $('#menu-overlay').fadeToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

[.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) the currently-running animation before starting a new one

or you can test if the element is in the progress of an animation with

[:animated selector](https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)

```js
jQuery('#menu-trigger').on('click', function(e) {
  //
  // if menu is animated do nothing and return
  //
  if ($('#menu').is(':animated')) {
      console.log('animation prevented');
      return;
  }
  if ($('#menu').offset().left != 0) {
      $('#menu').animate({
          "left": 0
      }, 'slow');
  } else {
      $('#menu').animate({
          "left": ($('body').width()-$('#menu').width())
      }, 'slow');
  }
});
```

```css
#menu {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" id="menu-trigger">menu trigger</button>
<div id="menu">

</div>
```

Comment: can you show this applied , i'm just learning and i've never worked with using stop() , much appreciated

Comment: @MShack A simple Snippet created. I preferred in this example to use the animated selector. In any case you may experience what can happen if you write .....$('#menu').stop().animate.....